# SSH error, switching between user on the same host - Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

Short explanation:

I'm able to connect with both users. My user + ec2-user to this instance machine in aws.

The problem occurs,
When I do ssh with `my-user@<host>` for example, if I do `exit` and then,
try to log in with `ec2-user` to the same host using `ss -i <key>`, I'm getting this error:

```
<my-user>@<host>: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

This happens vice versa, if I **destroy** the instance and re-deploy it, I'll be able to connect with the user I couldn't connect before, and then, the second user can't log in.
So only 1 user can log in with ssh to the current host - which is weird for me.

So what do I want to achieve?

Connecting with ssh with different users to the same host.

Thanks for helping,
Didn't find any other topics on that,

Niv

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: have you configured EC2 instance to accept ssh connection ?

Comment: In addition to posting on SuperUser, _show exactly what's happening._ Don't describe what you did, paste the _entire_ terminal session into your question.